# apache cxf - specify endpoint url

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have an tomcat instance running at port 8080 and a apache cxf webservice running at /services path. 
Now i dont want to expose this tomcat server directly so i use nginx as its proxy at port 80. The problem is the webservice endpoint is relative to the tomcat server so it is still at port 8080.

Is is possible to change this endpoint url so client's request will go to the nginx proxy ?

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming related question. It's more concerned with server configuration.

Comment: it still a programming related question as i think the solution might be adding an annotation to the code or at the cxf configuration

Answer (score 3):

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="aWebService"
    implementor="package.class"
    address="adressOfYourServer/nameOfYourService">

</jaxws:endpoint>
```

It's working for me